# Why am I unable to upload and store files/images from my React Frontend form to my Rails API backend, Active Storage installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, react-redux, rails-activestorage

I am creating a React application using Rails API backend.
I have a form component for my Organization model.

I need help properly storing a file/image from my frontend to my backend.

Before I began using Active Storage and adding the option to upload images to the form I was able to successfully submit a form for my Organization models. So that leads me to believe this is an isolated incident dealing with Active Storage

**On my backend**
I am using Active Storage and have 'has_many_attached :images' for my Organization model

**Org Model**

```
class Org < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
```

**Org Controller**

```
def create
        org = Org.create(org_params)
    
        if org.valid?
            render json: { org: OrgSerializer.new(org) }, status: :created
        else
            render json: { error: 'failed to create org' }, status: :not_acceptable
        end 

        byebug
end
```

(Does not even hit my byebug)

**Org Params**

```
 def org_params
        params.require(:org).permit(..., :images=[])
 end
```

Unsure if the params suppose to be ":images=[]" or "images: []"

**Org Serializer**

```
attributes ..., :images

def images
    rails_blob_path(object.images, only_path: true) if object.images.attached?
end
```

- On my frontend I am using a React class form component and storing the information in state

**State**

```
state = {
        ..., 
        images: [],
```

***Form input***

```
                        <label><strong>Add Organization Image: </strong></label>
                        <input 
                        accept="image/*"
                        multiple={true}
                        type="file"
                        name='images'
                        onChange={this.onFileChange}
                        />
```

**Uploading File function**

```
onFileChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0]
        })
    }
```

**On Form Submit Function**

```
handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const data = new FormData()
        Object.keys(this.state).forEach((key, value) => {
            return data.append(key, this.state[key])
        })
        
        const reqObj = {
            method: 'POST', 
            headers: {
                //Take this out
            }, 
            body: data
        }

        fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/orgs", reqObj)
        .then(newOrg => {
            this.props.addOrg(newOrg)

            this.props.history.push('/organizations')
        })
    }
```

As stated before, when I submit this form I do not even hit my byebug so I can inspect, instead I receive the following in my terminal:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/orgs" for ::1 at 2020-12-31 22:13:57 -0600
Processing by Api::V1::OrgsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {..., "images"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f99f2d66300 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/wq/_w197c7s5ns8wzw8l1wjf_k80000gn/T/RackMultipart20201231-6328-3buku3.jpg>, @original_filename="image3.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images\"; filename=\"image3.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, 
Completed 400 Bad Request in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 121)


  
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: org):
  
app/controllers/api/v1/orgs_controller.rb:46:in `org_params'
app/controllers/api/v1/orgs_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

Comment: You could try this: `const data = new FormData(e.target);` and don't append anything to it. If that doesn't work maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Dealing_with_binary_data) helps

Comment: `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: org)` this says that there is an issue with the `org` parameter not being found and triggered by `require(:org)`. Can you check if in the params you are sending the `org` param is also set?

Comment: @HMR I tried to not append anything and received: ```TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.```

Comment: @DanielSindrestean I believe that contributes to the issue.  When i place a debugger on the front end and take a look at the data sent... It is not the same data that I put in the form. I have not seen any legitimate resources on how to send the information to the backend other than what I have...

Comment: Appending is fine, do you have an `org` key that you are appending as well in the data obj?

Comment: @DanielSindrestean I do not.  Could you show me how to set up my data obj properly?

Comment: If you do not send an org param, you should just remove the `require(:org)` from your `org_params` so you'll have `params.permit(..., :images=[])`